# How to comment multiple lines with space or indent

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, comments

In Visual Studio 2010, I have multiple lines of text to be commented:

```
A
B
C
```

Using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to comment out multiple lines, I get

```
//A
//B
//C
```

I would like to have a space (or indent) between **//** and **A**, hence `// A` instead of `//A`.

However, after I group tab a block of text and indent it, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> no longer comments out the selected text.

How to group comment and get the following:

```
// A
// B
// C
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

One way to do it would be:

1. Select the text, Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd> to comment (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> )
2. Move the cursor to the first line after the delimiter `//` and before the Code text.
3. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> and use arrow keys to make selection. *(Remember to make line selection(using down, up arrow keys), not the text selection - See [Box Selection and Multi line editing](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/26/box-selection-and-multi-line-editing-with-vs-2010.aspx))*
4. Once the selection is done, press space bar to enter a single space.

Notice the vertical blue line in the below image( that will appear once the selection is made, then you can insert any number of characters in between them)

[image]

I couldn't find a direct way to do that. The interesting thing is that it is mentioned in the [C# Coding Conventions (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ff926074.aspx) under Commenting Conventions.

> Insert one space between the comment delimiter (//) and the comment
>   text

But the default implementation of commenting in visual studio doesn't insert any space

Comment: I do not see the blue vertical line. My Alt+Shift only allows me to select all to the left or to the right.

Comment: @KMC, press Alt + Shift + Down arraw key together, without releasing any one of them. There won't be any selection but a blue line.

Comment: @KMC, See this link for Multiline editing feature in VS 2012 . http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vseditor/archive/2009/05/25/the-new-box-selection-now-with-multi-line-editing.aspx and http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/26/box-selection-and-multi-line-editing-with-vs-2010.aspx

Comment: I only get the blue line by Alt+Shift+Down+Cursor-Select (I used my third hand to operate the mouse), and because the text are selected I can only do indent but not space (deleting).

Comment: @KMC, I am not sure why it is behaving like that, Did you see video in the links I posted ?

Comment: oh I figured. I was box-selecting the comment block and I should select on the same column without selecting any text. Thanks for the trick +1

Comment: You also can skip step 1 and type slash + slash + space instead of a single space step 4. I think this might be even easier.

Comment: *But the default implementation of commenting in visual studio doesn't insert any space* --> This is probably because the coding convention you quoted only applies to commentary, not to commented code. And commenting command in VS is quite always used to comment code. If you want to insert commentary, you just begin the line with `//`.

Answer (score 50):

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> After selecting the lines you want to comment will not give space after slashes. you can use multiline select to provide space as suggested by Habib

Perhaps, you can use /* before the lines you want to comment and after */ in that case you might not need to provide spaces.

```
/*
  First Line to Comment
  Second Line to Comment
  Third Line to Comment      
*/
```

Comment: This is an answer, but not to the original question. It says (in my words): "How do I change VS so that a comment generated by shortcut has a space after the comment sign?".
It would be interesting if there is a solution for that.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to achieve the desired result by using **Alt + Shift  + up/down** and then typing the desired comment characters and additional character.

Answer (score 3):

- You can customize every short cut operation according to your habbit.

Just go to Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard > Find the action you want to set key board short-cut and change according to keyboard habbit.

Comment: Thanks for everything.

Answer (score 1):

Might just be for Visual Studio '15, if you right-click on source code, there's an option for `insert comment`

This puts `summary` tags around your comment section, but it does give the indentation that you want.